# How to extract URLs from text

Tags: ruby

How do I extract all URLs from a plain text file in Ruby?

I tried some libraries but they fail in some cases. What's the best way?

Comment: Which libraries have you tried, and in what way are they failing?

Comment: When asking a question like this, we expect to see your attempt at solving the problem. We're happy to help fix your code, but asking us to write code for you is off-topic. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What cases are failing?

According to the library [regexpert](http://github.com/matthewrudy/regexpert/blob/master/lib/regexpert.rb), you can use

```
regexp = /(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix
```

and then perform a `scan` on the text.

EDIT: Seems like the regexp supports the empty string. Just remove the initial `(^$)` and you're done

Comment: Interesting how this regex fails when the URL is an IP address

Comment: Yep. I actually voted up on your answer because of the "and adjust it according to your needs". It also fails when present a user@password, or using other than https?, or any other weird situation. You probably wouldn't want to read http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 to get started -_-

Comment: It fails as above. I am asking here just why i am unable to "and adjust it according to your needs".

Comment: Using built in ruby methods shown in other answers seems to be a much cleaner solution. This probably shouldn't be selected as the best answer.

Answer (score 108):

If you like using what's already provided for you in Ruby:

```
require "uri"
URI.extract("text here http://foo.example.org/bla and here mailto:test@example.com and here also.")
# => ["http://foo.example.org/bla", "mailto:test@example.com"]
```

Read more: http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.8/classes/URI.html#M004495

Comment: It fails on text with ":" http://blog.apptamers.com/post/48613650042/uri-extract-incorrect-in-ruby-1-9-3

Comment: `URI.extract(yourString, /http(s)?|mailto/)`

Comment: There is anyway to extract urls without schema? like www.example.com

Comment: Appreciate the standard lib functionality, great for most cases. Worth noting the [postrank-uri](https://github.com/postrank-labs/postrank-uri) gem also has a similar extract method `PostRank::URI.extract(text)` which seems to handle more edge cases.

Answer (score 14):

I've used [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) gem

```
require "twitter-text"
class UrlParser
    include Twitter::Extractor
end

urls = UrlParser.new.extract_urls("http://stackoverflow.com")
puts urls.inspect
```

Comment: with newers versions you need to include include Twitter::TwitterText::Extractor, instead of include Twitter::Extractor

Answer (score 9):

You can use regex and [`.scan()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812)

```
string.scan(/(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/)
```

You can get started with that regex and adjust it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If your input looks similar to this:

```
"http://i.imgur.com/c31IkbM.gifv;http://i.imgur.com/c31IkbM.gifvhttp://i.imgur.com/c31IkbM.gifv"
```

i.e. URLs do not necessarily have white space around them, can be delimited by any delimiter, or have no delimiter between them at all, you can use the following approach:

```
def process_images(raw_input)
  return [] if raw_input.nil?
  urls = raw_input.split('http')
  urls.shift
  urls.map { |url| "http#{url}".strip.split(/[\s\,\;]/)[0] }
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

```
require 'uri'    
foo = #<URI::HTTP:0x007f91c76ebad0 URL:http://foobar/00u0u_gKHnmtWe0Jk_600x450.jpg>
foo.to_s
=> "http://foobar/00u0u_gKHnmtWe0Jk_600x450.jpg"
```

**edit: explanation**

For those who are having problems parsing URI's through JSON responses or by using a scraping tool like Nokogiri or Mechanize, this solution worked for me.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your answer? If it indeed is an answer?

Comment: Additional explanation added.

Comment: This makes no sense and isn't syntactically correct.