# Nokogiri select hyperlinks from XML::NodeSet

Tags: ruby, xml, rss, nokogiri

I have written the following simple script to parse reddit/r/documentaries

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

top_docs = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.reddit.com/r/Documentaries/top.rss"))
top_docs.xpath('//item').each do |documentary|
    documentary_description = documentary.xpath('description')
end
```

I am trying to gather an array of all the hyperlinks within documentary_description. What selector / method should I use to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`extract`](http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.8/classes/URI.html#M004495) method provided by URI:

```
top_docs.xpath('//item').each do |documentary|
  documentary_description = documentary.xpath('description')
  links = URI.extract(documentary_description.text)
  ...
end
```

Comment: To give credit where credit is due: I discovered the `extract` method from this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665072/extract-url-from-text#9716632 Might use it myself in the future, very handy!

Comment: Why not just `search('a')`, are the links in plaintext?

Answer (score 2):

One-liner (using the handy `URI#extract` noted by @shioyama):

```
links = URI.extract(top_docs.xpath('//item/description').to_a.join(" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with URI#extract, In this case it picks up a probably unwanted img src. Nokogiri is more reliable:

```
links = Nokogiri::HTML(documentary_description.text).search('a').map{|x| x[:href]}
```

Comment: Of course, one could also add `*[not(self::img)]` to any XPath and exclude them from `extract` that way.